# discorod.py error In channel_id: Value "<built-in function id>" is not snowflake

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    if CheckIfChapterIsOut():
        with open("chapter.txt", "r") as f:
            chapter = f.readline()
        print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(id)
        print(id)
        await channel.send(f"Chapter {chapter} Of Overgeared is out!")
        await channel.send(
            f"https://mangarockteam.com/manga/overgeared-team-argo/chapter-{chapter}/"
        )


client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

error is (part of):

```
In channel_id: Value "<built-in function id>" is not snowflake.
```

there's more code, variables are established before and CheckIfChapterIsOut function is returning True

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Since you never declared id, python thinks the id that you passed in as a parameter is the id() built-in.

Comment: I had it declared as private variable in replit, but after I put it in manually, it worked.